# Uso de def __unicode__(self):

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Uso Django 1.9. Tengo dos modelos relacionados entre sí, uno contiene un id y nombre entre otros atributos y el otro contiene su propio id junto con el id del primer modelo:

```
class Televisor(models.Model):
    idTelevisor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    ...

class Falla(model.Models):
    idFalla = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idTelevisor = ForeignKey(Televisor)
    ...
```

Sin embargo, en el admin de django quisiera que para el segundo modelo, los nombres de los objetos salieran utilizando los atributos contenidos en el primer modelo. Cosa que me ha sido imposible realizar con la sintaxis que describiré después, puesto que me sale un error de ObjectHasNoAttribute.

En ese caso, cuál es la sintaxis? Por ejemplo, tengo ésta sintaxis, pero que provoca errores por no existir los atributos en el segundo modelo:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.televisor.Marca, self.televisor.Modelo, self.televisor.VarianteModelo)
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes poner una versión simplificada de tus modelos? y el error que te sale?

Comment: Creo que necesitas agregar números para cada corchete: `{0}{1}{2}`.

Answer (score 2):

Al final no era necesario describir así los atributos que quería que se mostraran como nombre en el admin de Django, sólo bastaba con colocar el id que resultaba ser la ForeignKey:

```
class Falla(models.Model):
   ...

    def __unicode__(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.idTelevisor)
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien lo del id, pero podrías relacionar los modelos de la siguiente forma, dado como ejemplo:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__():
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Gender(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book  = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__():
         return '{}'.format(self.book)
```

Luego modificar el modulo admin.py para añadir a tu interfaz de administración.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Register, User, Author, Gender
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Register)
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Gender)
```

Yo creo que con eso puedes relacionar el modelo 1 con el modelo 2, y puedes verificar en tu interfaz de administrador, como se crea la relación al llenar los campos.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no necesitas definir de esa manera tu clave primaria, ya que Django hace exactamente eso de forma automática. Es decir, puedes obviar el primer campo:

```
class Televisor(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    ...
```

Por otro lado, el error que mencionas se debe a que en tu modelo no tienes ningún campo llamado `televisor`. El nombre correcto, como ya descubriste, es `idTelevisor`.

Por último, la guía de estilo de Django [recomienda](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) que uses solo minúsculas en los nombres de tus campos, por lo que el modelo `Falla` se vería así:

```
class Falla(model.Models):
    televisor = ForeignKey(Televisor)
    ...
```